# $\lim_{x \to 0}(x^2(1+2+3+\cdots+[\frac {1} {|x|}]))$ where [a] is largest integer not greater than a and |x| is absolute value of x

Tags: calculus, limits

As x tends to 0, the first term $x^2$ tends to 0 while the second term tends to infinity. So is the limit undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $x>0$. Let be $n=\left[\frac1x\right]$. It is clear that $n\rightarrow\infty$ when $x\rightarrow0^+$.

Moreover, $n\leq\frac 1x<n+1$, so $\frac 1{n+1}<x\leq\frac1n$. Hence,

$$\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)^2\frac{n^2+n}2<x^2\sum_{k\leq [1/x]}k\leq\left(\frac1{n}\right)^2\frac{n^2+n}2$$

So the limit when $x\rightarrow0^+$ is $1/2$.

Proof for negative $x$ is similar.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is zero. Let $n=n(x):=[1/|x|]$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^ni=n(n+1)/2$, it follows that it suffices to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^2n(n+1)/2$$.

Clearly $1/x-1\leq n(x)\leq 1/x$. Now apply the Squeeze theorem to conclude the limit is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=\frac 1n,$ the sum of the whole numbers is $\frac 12n(n+1)$, so the limit is $\frac 12$

Comment: This is not a proof. $\sin(2\pi n)\rightarrow 0$ but $\sin(\frac{2\pi}x))$ has no limit when $x\rightarrow0$.

Comment: @ajotatxe:  It needs some fleshing out, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write mathematical expressions, so I'll tell you by words:
use the equation for sum from 1 to [1/abs(x)] and then use the inequality for the floor function and you will get limit 0.5